# The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'Nobody'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly

Tags: c#

```
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Nobody WHERE UseName = '"+txtUsername.Text+"' AND Password = '"+txtPassword.Text+"'";
```

I don't know what the problem is really. I'm new to programming so can you guys be a bit easy on me. Thanks

Comment: Is there a table called nobody in the selected database?

Comment: It seems to be a pretty straightforward error message. What do you not understand?